# The value from final variable give me minus

Tags: php

I try to make sum with various variables and it should give 200 on final response, but it gives me -200.

What is wrong with my code? Why does it return -200.

I want it to give me 200 on final sum.

My app sends an Ajax call with a variable `$Points` but for security I have made a sum with more two variables.

For example if the user has 200 points in the app, it will add the ntruck=412020 and truck=20201.

So on final it sends to the php script the value 432221+200=432421
When the script is loaded, it takes from total 432421-ntruck-truck so it will stay only the value of the points 200.

This Is my code:

```
<?php
$point = "432421";
$ntruck = "412020";
$truck = "20201";
$sum_total = $truck + $ntruck;
$npoints = $sum_total - $point;
$points = $npoints;
echo $points;
?>
```

But when I make an echo it gives me -200 where I have failed?

Well I liked it to the variable final give me 200.

Comment: Because that's how math *works*. `20201 + 412020 - 432421 = -200`. If you want the number to always be positive, check to see if it is negative and multiply by -1 or use `abs()`

Comment: Please check what you want and what you have done, when you perform all the calculation according to your code it will return -200. which is correct

Comment: RIP my eyes. You are getting a minus value because the total it is negative.

Comment: i have try to multiply the -200 by one like you say but it not change my final value i have try $points = $npoints*1

Comment: I have now seen it all.

Comment: Tanks All I Have Now Understand Now My Value Is Correct Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($points < 0)
{
    //number is negative, make it positive
    $points = $points * -1;
}
```